# Estimate UCM Equation from Ucm model?

Tags: time-series, sas, unobserved-components-model

Given the output of a ucm sas procedure i need to estimate the **equations from the given output** , but i don't really know how to do it or where to start. Do you have any hints or anything that might help me? (I read the SAS documentation and the likes, but there isn't any example).

It's the time series of the **logarithm of the number of passengers.**

These are the print screens i have

[image: Diagram]
[image: Represantion]

Anything would be really apreaciated!

Comment: It is not easy at all, can you let me know what is the type of seasonality that you have used ? is your trend/level/slope/ stochastic or deterministic ?

Comment: there are monthly values for an airline transport company. I guess everything is stohastic.

Comment: It's the time series of the logarithm of the number of passengers.

Comment: All the necessary equations are in the following sas [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ets/132/ucm.pdf) and this [article](http://www.gwu.edu/~forcpgm/SiemJanKoopman-final-2010UCForecasting.pdf) by Koopman who along with Harvey invented this class of methods. I have never personally  attempted to formulate an equation, because it's complex, involves recursive calculations and equations.